# Angular mat-autocomplete doesn't work with options returned by function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have took autocomplete example from Material official web site and changed getting options from variable of component class to function, options display but I can't select anything, clicking on drop-down doesn't select a value.

[Here is sample project on StackBlitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tica2t?file=src/app/autocomplete-simple-example.html)

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options()" [value]="option">
    {{option.value}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>

export class AutocompleteSimpleExample {
  myControl = new FormControl();
  options(): KeyValue[] {
    return [{ key: "1", value: "One" }];
  }
}
interface KeyValue {
  key: string;
  value: string;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the data source of ngFor returned by function, Clicking mat-option trigger a change detection, which cause ngFor to get a new array and generate a new mat-option due to which the selection is not working. you can prevent this by using trackBy function

**component.html**

```
 <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options();trackBy:trackByIdentity" [value]="option">
        {{option.value}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
    <!-- #enddocregion mat-autocomplete -->
  </mat-form-field>
```

**component.ts**

```
trackByIdentity:TrackByFunction<{key:string,value:string}> = (index: number, item: any) => item.key;
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-angular-mat-autocomplete-doesnt-work-with-options-retur?file=src/app/autocomplete-simple-example.ts)

Comment: I think the `[value]=option` should be `[value]=option.value` to show the actual value. I could be wrong

Comment: @Maddy Yes you are correct. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: It's because you have assigned [value]="someObject"  so everytime change detection happen selected formControl object and generated mat-option object value comparision will fail as option method return new array on every change detection({} === {})